# How to correct checkout and what after it

Tags: git

I want to restore all my files to a commit.

I'm doing:

```
git checkout commit
```

on remote server and files are restored

what exactly should i do after it on local and remote?

Do i need to create new branch and merge ?

Comment: It depends on what your end goal is, which you didn't state. Can you explain why you think that command isn't enough?

Comment: Do you want to lose history after that commit, or do you want a new commit at the top of the history, with the state from that older commit?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset your current branch to some commit, then use:

```
git reset --hard <some commit hash>
```

Keep in mind that this will move the entire HEAD to this other commit, thereby wiping out your working directory and stage.  Only use this option if you are certain that you really want to do this.

Comment: I need to restore all my files to commit and then I dont now what to do. after all I want create a new commit and continue commiting. Nothing to commit message shows ,when I change some files after it i have merge conflicts

Comment: My answer should do that (assuming I understand correctly).

Comment: Thank you. Should i do this on both machines?

Comment: What is the other machine here?

Comment: first is remote server and other my local computer

Comment: In general, Git commands run locally, on your own computer.  If you go with the option I suggested above, you should use a force push to the remote, i.e. `git push --force origin your_branch`

Comment: ok, but everything is up to date ;] and commit does not show on github after this